# BeautifulSoup4 not able to scrape data from this table

Tags: python, html, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Sorry for this silly question as I'm new to web scraping and have no knowledge about HTML etc.

I'm trying to scrape data from [this website](http://data.eastmoney.com/xg/xg/detail/300741.html?tr_zqh=1). Specifically, from this part/table of the page:

[image]

*末"四"位数 9775,2275,4775,7275
末"五"位数  03881,23881,43881,63881,83881,16913,66913
末"六"位数  313110,563110,813110,063110
末"七"位数  4210962,9210962,9785582
末"八"位数  63262036
末"九"位数  080876872*

I'm sorry that's in Chinese and it looks terrible since I can't embed the picture. However, The table is roughly in the middle(40 percentile from the top) of the page. The table id is `'tr_zqh'`.

Here is my source code:

```
import bs4 as bs
import urllib.request

def scrapezqh(url):
    source = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
    page = bs.BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')
    print(page)

url = 'http://data.eastmoney.com/xg/xg/detail/300741.html?tr_zqh=1'
print(scrapezqh(url))
```

It scrapes most of the table but the part that I'm interested in. Here is a part of what it returns where I think the data should be:

```
<td class="tdcolor">网下有效申购股数(万股)
            </td>
<td class="tdwidth" id="td_wxyxsggs"> 
            </td>
</tr>
<tr id="tr_zqh">
<td class="tdtitle" id="td_zqhrowspan">中签号
            </td>
<td class="tdcolor">中签号公布日期
            </td>
<td class="ltxt" colspan="3"> 2018-02-22 (周四)
            </td>
```

I'd like to get the content of this table: `tr id="tr_zqh"` (the 6th row above). However for some reason it doesn't scrape its data(No content below). However, when I check the source code of the webpage, the data are in the table. I don't think it is a dynamic table which BeautifulSoup4 can't handle. I've tried both `lxml` and html parser and I've tried `pandas.read_html`.  It returned the same results. I'd like to get some help to understand why it doesn't get the data and how I can fix it. Many thanks!

Forgot to mention that I tried `page.find('tr')`, it returned a part of the table but not the lines I'm interested. `Page.find('tr')` returns the 1st line of the screenshot. I want to get the data of the 2nd & 3rd line(highlighted in the screenshot)
[image]

Comment: Thanks, @WorldSEnder! I forgot to mention that I've tried page.find('tr'). It returns only the first line of the table. I attached a screenshot of the line that I'm interested but couldn't find here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGho1.png. I just tried page.find(id='tr_zqh'). still not finding the line I'm interested (the line with number"9775, 2275 4775, 7275")

Comment: That part of the data is actually loaded asynchronously with javascript

Comment: Good to know! Thanks, @WorldSEnder!

Comment: you might want to take a look into the cefpython framework for an embedded browser. It will be a bit more complicated though

Comment: It does look pretty advanced for me but really cool that you can embed a web browser in a Python application. Thanks for the info.

Comment: You could also use Selenium to deal with page that use JavaScript. It's pretty easy to use.

Comment: Try a different parser

Comment: @KeyurPotdar Ok, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you extract a couple of variables from the initial page you can use themto make a request to the api directly. Then you get a json object which you can use to get the data.

```
import requests
import re
import json
from pprint import pprint

s = requests.session()
r = s.get('http://data.eastmoney.com/xg/xg/detail/300741.html?tr_zqh=1')
gdpm = re.search('var gpdm = \'(.*)\'', r.text).group(1)
token  = re.search('http://dcfm.eastmoney.com/em_mutisvcexpandinterface/api/js/get\?type=XGSG_ZQH&token=(.*)&st=', r.text).group(1)

url = "http://dcfm.eastmoney.com/em_mutisvcexpandinterface/api/js/get?type=XGSG_ZQH&token=" + token + "&st=LASTFIGURETYPE&sr=1&filter=%28securitycode='" + gdpm + "'%29&js=var%20zqh=%28x%29"
r = s.get(url)
j = json.loads(r.text[8:])

for i in range (len(j)):
    print ( j[i]['LOTNUM'])


#pprint(j)
```

Outputs:

```
9775,2275,4775,7275
03881,23881,43881,63881,83881,16913,66913
313110,563110,813110,063110
4210962,9210962,9785582
63262036
080876872
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I'm looking for!

Comment: Sorry for one more question: would this be the optimal code if I need to go through 2000 similar pages. My initial thought is to iterate the code through every page, however it would need to connect to the sever 4000 times. I'm wondering whether there is a better way or this is already the best. Any thought would be helpful!

Comment: Unfortunately I can't find documentation for the API. It is possible the API will return more, even all, of the values you want in one request, but maybe it won't. What I would do is compare the API URLs from two different requests and find the differences. Then try querying the API in different ways based on the differences.

Answer (score 0):

From where I look at things your question isn't clear to me. But here's what I did.

I do a lot of webscraping so I just made a package to get me beautiful soup objects of any webpage. Package is [here](https://github.com/immensity/pywebber).
So my answer depends on that. But you can take a look at the sourcecode and see that there's really nothing esoteric about it. You may drag out the `soup-making` part and use as you wish.

Here we go.

```
pip install pywebber --upgrade

from pywebber import PageRipper

page = PageRipper(url='http://data.eastmoney.com/xg/xg/detail/300741.html?tr_zqh=1', parser='html5lib')

page_soup = page.soup

tr_zqh_table = page_soup.find('tr', id='tr_zqh')
```

from here you can do `tr_zqh_table.find_all('td')`

```
tr_zqh_table.find_all('td')
```

Output

```
[
<td class="tdtitle" id="td_zqhrowspan">中签号
</td>, <td class="tdcolor">中签号公布日期
</td>, <td class="ltxt" colspan="3"> 2018-02-22 (周四)
</td>
]
```

Going a bit further

```
for td in tr_zqh_table.find_all('td'):
    print(td.contents)
```

Output

```
['中签号\n                ']
['中签号公布日期\n                ']
['\xa02018-02-22 (周四)\n                ']
```

Comment: This is just little more complicated way to get the same output as OP already got. She wants dynamic values while your code returns static values from initial page source

Comment: Thanks@Parousia for sharing the package! I did want to get the dynamic values (the numbers:'9775,2275,4775,7275'). Thanks@Andersson for the clarification!